# Startup disk creator: Installation failed

Tags: usb-installation

I'm trying to create a startup disk on ubuntu 19.04 using the startup disk creator, but after selecting the image (ubuntu 19.04) and the disk (/dev/mmcblk0), it just throws up an error: Could not write the disk image /home/karl/Downloads/ubuntu-mate-19.04-desktop-amd64.iso to the device (/dev/mmcblk0)

Looking in syslog, I see this error:

Jul 19 09:00:11 tp-main com.ubuntu.USBCreator[897]: DEBUG:root:_check_polkit_privilege: sender :1.776 on connection  pid 19120 is not authorized for com.ubuntu.usbcreator.image: dbus.Dictionary({}, signature=dbus.Signature('ss'))

Comment: What happens if you insert a different USB flash drive and check its device name in the Disks application? The device name of the USB flash drive should be something like /dev/sd**X**

Comment: make sure you have sudo or root privilege to make bootable drive.

Comment: In versions of Ubuntu, that have passed end of life, and where you can no longer install programs from the repositories, but you can run a web browser, you can install [**mkusb-min**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/min) and use it in a terminal window (or in text mode) to create a live system in a USB drive or memory card.

Answer (score 8):

Try from the command-line with root privileges:

```
sudo usb-creator-gtk
```

Comment: Huh, I can't believe that just worked. Thanks! Such a simple solution, I feel silly I didn't try it.

Comment: This worked for me with
```sudo usb-creator-kde``` as well

Answer (score 0):

/dev/mmcblk0 indicates you tried to install the Live image to an SD or MMC card. Neither are suitable to boot from on many PCs; they are not USB flash drives, which work on nearly all PCs which met Ubuntu minimum requirements (although some older PCs won't even boot from USB flashdrives and require a LiveCD or LiveDVD).

Comment: Some computers can boot from memory cards recognized as mmcblk devices. I have such a Dell laptop.